# MiniProfiler setup - A null was returned after calling the 'get_ProviderFactory' method

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, mvc-mini-profiler, database-first

After hours of struggling with MiniProfiler to make it profile the Database queries, I have no luck and I'm getting the error:

> A null was returned after calling the 'get_ProviderFactory' method on
>   a store provider instance of type
>   'StackExchange.Profiling.Data.ProfiledDbConnection'. The store
>   provider might not be functioning correctly.

I got through many SO posts but nothing has worked so far, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17008892/a-null-was-returned-after-calling-the-get-providerfactory-method-on-a-store-pr) post which is about the same error but with different configuration and well there's not an answer. Now I know that `ProfiledDbConnection` is not overriding `DbProviderFactory` and it's parent class `DbConnection` returns null in it's implementation of `DbProviderFactory` so the error is expectable but it should work somehow. There is a `MiniProfilerEF.Initialize()` but it seams to be usable for CodeFirst only and I'm using DatabaseFirst approach.

I have installed MiniProfiler, MiniProfiler.EF, MiniProfilerMVC3 nuget packages. And here is my code:

```
        string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SqlConnection"].ConnectionString;
        var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        var profiled = new ProfiledDbConnection(sqlConnection, MiniProfiler.Current);
        var db = new DbContext(profiled, true);
        db.Set<Customer>().ToList();
```

And I'm using asp.net mvc4, EF5, DatabseFirst, MiniProfiler 2.1.0.0, Sql Server

Any Idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, coming from your comment on [Setup of mvc-mini-profiler for EF-db- first](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7287910/11912), have you tried removing the Mini Profiler-specific wrapper?

```
var profiled = new ProfiledDbConnection(sqlConnection, MiniProfiler.Current);
var db = new DbContext(profiled, true);
db.Set<Customer>().ToList();
```

Instead, just adding

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    // any other code
    MiniProfilerEF.Initialize();
}
```

and then doing standard db access?

```
using (var db = new WordsEntities()) {
    var posts = db.Customer.Take(4);
    // more code
}
```

Comment: That's the one I haven't had tried, and now it's working fine, thanks a lot. I should have investigated the initialize method more deeply and avoid the misleading comment on that line:   `//TODO: If you are profiling EF code first try: 
            //MiniProfilerEF.Initialize();`